# CentOS 6.5 proxy bypass/no_proxy not working

Tags: linux, bash, proxy, linux-networking, http-proxy

I am running CentOS 6.5 on my desktop. I've set the `Network Proxy` using the network proxy application provided under `Preferences`. I've also set the following exceptions: localhost,127.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0./16

But whenever I am using wget (I'm testing the proxy settings using using wget) then wget tries to connect to the proxy for private addresses, but `wget localhost` works fine and doesn't use the proxy.

I also removed all the proxy settings and set the proxy in the shell:

```
export http_proxy="<proxy_url>:<port>"
export https_proxy="<proxy_url>:<port>"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0./16"
```

It work when I use the command `wget <external_url>` or `wget localhost` but fails when I use the command `wget <private address from the $no_proxy variable>`.

I also tried setting the variables in Ubuntu 14.04 also and facing the same issue.

Edit: I've found that the shell is ignoring the CIDR notation. If I need to browse 127.0.0.1 without a proxy then I need to input 127.0.0.1 in `no_proxy` variable instead of 127.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have and extra dot on one of the ranges:

```
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16"
```

**EDIT:**

After searching, it seems no_proxy won't work with networks, only domains `.sample.com` or exact IP `192.168.1.2`, so either you add your local domain, all the IP your network has, or you use flags like `wget --no-proxy`

Comment: Thanks! It's still not working though. I've found that the shell is ignoring the CIDR notation. If I need to browse 127.0.0.1 without a proxy then I need to input 127.0.0.1 in no_proxy variable instead of 127.0.0.0/8

Answer (score 0):

If we need to exclude 192.168.1.0/24 from proxy setting, we can set environment variable no_proxy as below:

```
export no_proxy=localhost,.localdomain
export no_proxy=${no_proxy},$(echo 192.168.1.{1..255} | sed 's/ /,/g')
```

Comment: That is impractical for large networks, such as 10.0.0.0/8.